# Speeding up the fragmentation of a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, split, snapshot-view

I have the following code (within an extension of `UIView`) that fragments a `UIView` into a certain number of pieces:

```
public func fragment(into numberOfFragments: Int) -> [UIView] {

        var fragments = [UIView]()    

        guard let containerView = superview, let snapshot = snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) else { return fragments }

        let fragmentWidth = snapshot.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfFragments)
        let fragmentHeight = snapshot.frame.height / CGFloat(numberOfFragments)

        for x in stride(from: 0.0, to: snapshot.frame.width, by: fragmentWidth) {
            for y in stride(from: 0.0, to: snapshot.frame.height, by: fragmentHeight) {

                let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: fragmentWidth, height: fragmentHeight)

                if let fragment = snapshot.resizableSnapshotView(from: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true, withCapInsets: .zero) {        

                    fragment.frame = convert(rect, to: containerView)
                    containerView.addSubview(fragment)
                    fragments.append(fragment)

                }

            }

        }

        return fragments

    }
```

However, for `numberOfFragments=20` this code takes about 2 seconds to complete. Is there any way of achieving this same result in a faster way? **Should I be using an animation/transition instead?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are looking at a decent amount (and 20 is clearly that) amount to"break up an image", you should not be using nothing but `UIKit` and `UIView`. You're hitting a threshold to look into using the CPU. It'll require one refactoring but *at least* CoreGraphics, maybe more. (It does depend on more details.)

Comment: @dfd Thanks for your advice. To confirm, are you suggesting that I look into using CoreGraphics, or that this is a CPU limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses UIImageViews instead of UIViews. It crops a single captured screenshot instead of calling the much more expensive `resizableSnapshotView` 400 times.  Time went from ~2.0 seconds down to 0.088 seconds if `afterScreenUpdates` is set to false (which works for my test case). If `afterScreenUpdates` is required for your purposes, then the time is about 0.15 seconds. Still - much much faster than 2.0 seconds!

```
public func fragment(into numberOfFragments: Int) -> [UIImageView] {

    var fragments = [UIImageView]()

    guard let containerView = superview else { return fragments }

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: containerView.bounds.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        containerView.drawHierarchy(in: containerView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    }

    let fragmentWidth = containerView.frame.width / CGFloat(numberOfFragments)
    let fragmentHeight = containerView.frame.height / CGFloat(numberOfFragments)

    for x in stride(from: 0.0, to: containerView.frame.width, by: fragmentWidth) {
        for y in stride(from: 0.0, to: containerView.frame.height, by: fragmentHeight) {

            let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: fragmentWidth, height: fragmentHeight)

            if let imageFrag = cropImage(image, toRect: rect) {
                let fragment = UIImageView(image: imageFrag)
                fragment.frame = convert(rect, to: containerView)
                containerView.addSubview(fragment)
                fragments.append(fragment)
            }
        }
    }

    return fragments

}


func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, toRect cropRect: CGRect) -> UIImage?
{

    let imageViewScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    // Scale cropRect to handle images larger than shown-on-screen size
    let cropZone = CGRect(x:cropRect.origin.x * imageViewScale,
                          y:cropRect.origin.y * imageViewScale,
                          width:cropRect.size.width * imageViewScale,
                          height:cropRect.size.height * imageViewScale)

    // Perform cropping in Core Graphics
    guard let cutImageRef: CGImage = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to:cropZone)
        else {
            return nil
    }

    // Return image to UIImage
    let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
    return croppedImage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, works well. However, `containerView.drawHierarchy` should just be `drawHierarchy` (and likewise in a few other places) as it's really the `UIView` itself that I'd like to fragment (rather than the `superview`). Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Cheers, glad it works for you. Sorry about that, guess I must have been a bit confused! ;)

Comment: BTW: just curious, but is this for some kind of screen exploding animation?

Comment: Yep exactly - so pass it a `UICollectionViewCell` that you want to delete say, ( `let fragments cell.fragment ....`) and then remove the `fragments` from the `superview` after some sort of animation of the `fragment`s `x` and `y` positions. :-)